# How to obtain map (array) values given a floating-point set of coordinates?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have two 2-dimensional arrays (of astronomical data) and a set of corresponding coordinates for both of them (for each star). Both arrays are projections of these data maps on the sky and the $(x,y)$ coordinates are the sky-to-pixel transformations given each map's metadata.

The sky-to-pixel coordinates are all floating point values (say, $x=13.5$ and $y=32.2$). What I've done so far is just to truncate these coordinates and check the values there (say, $x=13$ and $y=32$). I was wondering, though, if there's a more pythonic way (or more practical) in which I just check the floating point coordinates and get the corresponding map value?

Comment: Please show us your code and sample data.  Your description is too vague.

Comment: SciPy has some interpolation functions that might interest you for this problem: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#interpolation-scipy-interpolate